How to checkout using stripe and REACT JS without redirecting to a return url?
I want to accept payments using stripe and REACT JS without having confirmPayment redirect to a return url. I would like to create a token that gets sent to the node js backend that actually does the charging. How can I do that using Stripe and React JS?

Sounds like you want the "Finalize payments on the server" flow
